# Execute Shell Command from self-running .exe-file

Tags: java, shell, exe, runtime.exec

I exported my Java-Application to a self-running jar-file, then compiled it to an **.exe**-file using [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

I figured, that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec('shutdown -s -f -t <time in seconds>');` works only if I open the **.jar**-file from command-line. Running the compiled `.exe` from command-line doesn't work.

Why is that and is there any way to execute that command by simply opening the `.exe`-file?

Comment: What is the command you are using and what errors do you get?

Comment: why should `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<command>)` care about how it is started?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the command is 'shutdown -s -f -t <dynamic time>'